# Scaling issues with mtpro2 fonts + extarticle class

Tags: fontsize, scaling, mtpro

I'm using the mtpro2 fonts in combination with the extarticle class in xelatex (don't think this matters). I just want an article class where I can use a small font size, like 8pt or 9pt. Reason is that I need to prepare a handout for a 90min seminar talk which should be one A4 page, and I want to have a decent amount of information on it.

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[9pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.95]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[mtphrb]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
This is a test: $\mathcal H_\infty = \bigvee_{t \in \mathbb R_+} \mathcal H_t$
\end{document}
```

Output with 9pt:
[image: Scaling issue]

Output with 12pt:
[image: Scaling issue]

The \infty looks too big in the 9pt version, as does the + (although that is less critical).
I am not sure if this is accidental, because some settings don't match well, or if this is intended behavior (I could imagine why one would want this; anyway, I would like a screen-optimized rather than paper-optimized version).

Comment: If you can use `fontspec`, you can use `unicode-math` instead of `mtpro2` and `\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}`. This lets you use `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}` and scale all fonts in the document automatically.

Comment: I’m not sure what the issue is, however. The symbols look scaled to me.

Comment: The `mtpro2` package does not support a scaling option, and providing one would essentially involve re-writing the package yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think a generally-given piece of advice is that when working with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, `fontspec`, and legacy math font packages such as `mtpro2`, one should load `fontspec` with the option `no-math`.

With this precaution in place, the `extarticle` document class is very well able of scaling the math font as well as the text font. The following screenshots were created with XeLaTeX.

at 8pt

[image]

at 9pt

[image]

at 10pt

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{extarticle} % or: '9pt', '8pt', etc
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[mtphrb]{mtpro2}

\begin{document}
This is a test: $\mathcal{H}_\infty = \bigvee_{t\in\mathbb{R}_+} \mathcal{H}_t$
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the full mtpro2 fonts, so had to exchange by lite.

You can change the fontsizes used in sub- and subsubscripts with \DeclareMathSizes:

```
\RequirePackage{fix-cm} %
\documentclass[9pt, a4paper]{extarticle}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Scale=0.95]{Times New Roman}

\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\DeclareMathSizes{9}{9}{5}{3} %default 9 9 7 5.5
\begin{document}
This is a test: $\mathcal H_\infty = \bigvee_{t \in R_+} \mathcal H_t$
\end{document}
```

[image]